# Schedule batch predictions Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a forecasting model using AutoML on Vertex AI. I want to use this model to make batch predictions every week. Is there a way to schedule this?

The data to make those predictions is stored in a bigquery table, which is updated every week.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic scheduling directly in Vertex AutoML yet but many different ways to set this up in GCP.

Two options to try first using the client libraries available for BigQuery and Vertex:

- Cloud Scheduler to use cron https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart
- use either Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to setup a BigQuery event trigger, and then trigger the AutoML batch prediction.  Example to repurpose https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're using Vertex pipelines to run the prediction job but if you are there's a method to schedule your pipeline execution listed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/pipelines/pipelines_intro_kfp.ipynb).

```py
from kfp.v2.google.client import AIPlatformClient  # noqa: F811

api_client = AIPlatformClient(project_id=PROJECT_ID, region=REGION)

# adjust time zone and cron schedule as necessary
response = api_client.create_schedule_from_job_spec(
    job_spec_path="intro_pipeline.json",
    schedule="2 * * * *",
    time_zone="America/Los_Angeles",  # change this as necessary
    parameter_values={"text": "Hello world!"},
    # pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT  # this argument is necessary if you did not specify PIPELINE_ROOT as part of the pipeline definition.
)
```

Comment: Thanks Manu! Unfortunately, this is not possible for forecasting models, but it seems to be possible for classification for example. Vertex does not support creating an endpoint for a forecasting model as fas as I understand.